# How do I add InternetMessageHeaders to a reply message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using the Reply method on a Message:

```
var replyMessage= new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = body
    },
    InternetMessageHeaders = messageHeaders,
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = recipient
            }
        }
    },
    Attachments = attachments
};

graphClient.Me.Messages[replyToMessageId].Reply(replyMessage).Request().PostAsync();
```

My question is - how do I add to the InternetMessageHeaders on the reply - the above is not adding the headers. Using the same technique for SendMail, does however set the properties.

I have tried using CreateReply and then Updating the message - this also fails to add the headers.

Comment: How are you verifying the headers aren't there? Are you checking the message after it's sent from the recipient's side, from your Sent items, or during debug? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2716#issuecomment-393519252

Comment: I'm checking the headers by looking at the item in the sent items folder. The email that is sent using SendMail has the headers, but the email sent using Reply doesn't have them.

Comment: Yeah, check out that link. The headers don't get added until the server sends the message.

Comment: Yes - I'm looking at the sent items.

Comment: The items in the Sent Items are copies of the messages before they are sent. If you send one of those messages to yourself at another email address, you should see the headers. Check that link; it spells it out.

Comment: Ok. So there must a difference between SendMail and Reply, because SendMail has the headers! I am actually using the headers for getting the MessageID after it's sent by scanning the sent items. Is there a better way to get the MessageID?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202363/discussion-between-scott-durow-and-randy-slavey).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [CreateReply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method which will create the reply mail as a draft. Then you can set the internet message headers. After the message headers are added, you send it.

```cs
// Create reply draft
var message = await graphClient.Me.Messages[replyToMessageId]
                               .CreateReply(replyMessage)
                               .Request()
                               .PostAsync();
var messageWithHeaders = new Message()
{
   InternetMessageHeaders = messageHeaders
}

// Set the internet message headers on the draft.
await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(messageWithHeaders);

// Send the draft.
await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id].Send().Request().PostAsync();
```

**update**
Changed PatchAsync(messageWithHeaders) to UpdateAsync(messageWithHeaders)

Comment: Have you tried this? When I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: @ScottDurow I fixed the example to use UpdateAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work you can't add an internet message header on a reply mail. I solved my problem using a SingleValueExtendedProperty.